# Find the characteristic polynomial of the $n\times n$ matrix $A$, where $A_{ij}=(i-1)n+j$

Tags: linear-algebra, solution-verification

> Determine the characteristic polynomial of
> $$A=\begin{pmatrix}1&2&\cdots&n\\n+1&n+2&\cdots&2n\\\vdots&\vdots&&\vdots\\n^2-n+1&n^2-n+2&\cdots&n^2\end{pmatrix}\mbox{.}$$

Let $v_1=(1,1,...,1)$ and $v_2=(1,2,...,n)$. We have
$$Av_1=n^2(v_2-v_1)+\frac{n(n+1)}{2}v_1=\frac{-n^2+n}{2}v_1+n^2v_2$$
and
$$Av_2=\frac{n^2(n+1)}{2}(v_2-v_1)+\frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}{6}v_1=\frac{-n^3+n}{6}v_1+\frac{n^3+n^2}{2}v_2\mbox{.}$$
Since
$$\frac{-n^2+n}{2}\frac{n+1}{2}=\frac{-n^3+n}{4}\not=\frac{-n^3+n}{6}\mbox{,}$$
$Av_1, Av_2$ are linearly independent.

Evidently, the row space of $A$ = $\mbox{span}\{v_1,v_2\}$, so that $\mbox{rank}(A)=2$. Therefore, if we extend $\{v_1,v_2\}$ to an ordered basis $\beta=\{v_1,v_2,...,v_n\}$ for $\mathbb{R}^n$, then $Av_j\subset\mbox{span}\{Av_1,Av_2\}$, $j=1,2,...,n$. It follows that the matrix repensentation of the linear operator $T_A$ on $\mathbb{R}^n$ induced by $A$ in $\beta$ is of the form
$$[T_A]_\beta=\begin{pmatrix}E&F\\G&H\end{pmatrix}\mbox{,}$$
where
$$E=\begin{pmatrix}\frac{-n^2+n}{2}&\frac{-n^3+n}{6}\\n^2&\frac{n^3+n^2}{2}\end{pmatrix}\mbox{,}$$
$F$ is an $n-2\times 2$ matrix, and $G,H$ are zero matrices of appropriate sizes.

We conclude that the characteristic polynomial of $T_A$ and hence of $A$ is
$$f(t)=\det(E-tI_2)\det(H-tI_{n-2})=(-1)^nt^{n-2}\left[\left(t-\frac{-n^2+n}{2}\right)\left(t-\frac{n^3+n^2}{2}\right)-\frac{-n^3+n}{6}n^2\right]\mbox{.}$$

Does this look correct?

Comment: Yes, that looks correct.